# How can I express that 2 is the only prime number that is even using predicate logic

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I defined some predicates below:

$B(a)$: a is a prime number

$C(a, b)$: b is divisible by $a$

Let $a, b$ be integers greater than $1$

My attempt is below, but I am not sure whether it is correct.

$$\forall a\in \mathbb{Z}, a = 2 \Leftrightarrow B(a) \land C(a, 2) $$

Comment: You mean $ C(2,a) $.

Comment: Wouldn't 2 divides 2, and 2 is divisible by 2 be equivalent in this case?

Comment: But $a$ might not be 2. Remember, you're making a statement about *all* $a$.

Comment: You're technically right, but why do you insist on writing such a strange statement: "2 is the only number which is prime and a divisor of 2".  It's technically right, but what you were trying to say was "2 is the only number which is prime and even."  They're both true statements, but the latter is more useful and what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 3):

Your

> $$\forall a\in \mathbb{Z}, a = 2 \Leftrightarrow B(a) \land C(a, 2) $$

is correct

Even simpler would be:

> $$\forall a\in \mathbb{Z}, a = 2 \Leftrightarrow P(a) \land E(a) $$

where $P(x)$ stands for $x$ is prime (if you are using predicate letters, you might as well use something more 'suggestive') and $E(x)$ stands for $x$ is even

In fact, it seems weird that you do try to work out what 'even' means, but you don't do this for 'prime'.

So, I would say: either just stick with the $P$ and $E$ predicates, or work them both out.

If you do decide to work them both out, then it does make sense to use some $D(x,y)$ predicate that means $x$ is divisible by $y$. Because with that, you can define (as you did), $Even(x)$ as $D(x,2)$, and $Prime(x)$ as
$x \neq 1 \land \forall y (D(x,y) \to (y = 1 \lor y = x))$, and thus you would get:

> $$\forall x, x = 2 \Leftrightarrow (x \neq 1 \land \forall y (D(x,y) \to (y = 1 \lor y = x)) \land D(x,2))$$

Answer (score 1):

This is also known as a definite descriptions in  Bertrand Russell's [theory of descriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_descriptions),
There is only one $x$ satisify $P$:

$$\exists x_0, P(x_0)\wedge (\forall x_1,P(x_1)\rightarrow x_0=x_1)\tag{1}$$

There is only one $x$ satisify $P$, and that $x$ satisify $Q:$

$$\exists x_0, P(x_0)\wedge (\forall x_1,P(x_1)\rightarrow x_0=x_1)\land Q(x_0)\tag{2}$$

In some sense, this also read as $Q$ is the only thing satisify $P$.
So we want the property $P(x)$ be $x$ is prime and even, $Q$ be $x$ equal to $2$.
(Note that statement didn't claime the uniqueness of "been a $2$".)

Define$P(x):(\forall m,m\mid x\to(m=1\lor m=p))\land 2\mid x\tag{$x$ is prime, also even}$
Also $Q(x):x=2$, then In math notation, we can write:
\begin{align}
&\exists x_0, (\forall m,m\mid x_0\to(m=1\lor m=p))\land 2\mid x_0\\
&\wedge (\forall x_1,(\exists x_1, (\forall m,m\mid x_1\to(m=1\lor m=p))\land 2\mid x_1)\rightarrow x_0=x_1)\land x_0=2\\
\end{align}

Use predicates, that is same as $(2)$.